# JDBC: Implement exception handling and transaction rollback on error

Tags: java, jdbc

I have the below code which I wanted to review and understand how I can add a rollback step when something fails.

```
/**
 * Insert some data into some table in bulk
 *
 * @param requestData requested data
 */
private void insertingRowsByBatches(RequestData requestData) {
    try (
            Connection connection = myDataSource.getConnection();
            Statement deleteStatement = connection.createStatement()
    ) {
        connection.setAutoCommit(TRUE);
        String stagingDeleteSql = buildMessage("DELETE FROM my_table");
        int rowsAffected = deleteStatement.executeUpdate(stagingDeleteSql);
        log.info("[{}] records deleted", rowsAffected);

        String stagingInsertSql = "INSERT INTO my_table(SOME_DATA) values(?)";
        Lists.partition(Optional.ofNullable(requestData.getData()).orElse(emptyList()), MAX_ROWS_PER_INSERT)
                .forEach(recordIds -> {
                    try (PreparedStatement pstmt = connection.prepareStatement(stagingInsertSql, RETURN_GENERATED_KEYS)) {
                        for (String recordId: recordIds ) {
                            pstmt.setString(1, recordId);
                            pstmt.addBatch();
                        }
                        long start = currentTimeMillis();
                        pstmt.executeBatch();
                        long end = currentTimeMillis();
                        log.info("Total time taken to insert [{}] rows: {}ms", recordIds.size(), (end - start));
                    } catch (SQLException ex) {
                        log.error("Staging job failed due to an exception: {}", ex.getMessage());
                    }
                });
        connection.commit();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        throw new GenericRuntimeException(e);
    }
}
```

I'm a bit concerned on how this code will work if I get a `SQLException` in the loop for some reason. I wish to rollback all changes in proper ACID way.

**UPDATE**

After looking at the suggestions, this is what I came up with:

```
/**
 * Insert some data into some table in bulk
 *
 * @param requestData requested data
 */
public void insertingRowsByBatches(RequestData requestData) {
    try (Connection connection = myDataSource.getConnection()) {
            loadInStagingTable(requestData, connection);
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        throw new GenericRuntimeException(e);
    }
}

/**
 * Insert given data to staging table
 *
 * @param requestData requested data
 * @param connection instance of {@link Connection}
 * @throws SQLException exception
 */
private void loadInStagingTable(RequestData requestData, Connection connection) throws SQLException {
    try (
            PreparedStatement deleteStatement = connection.prepareStatement("DELETE FROM my_table");
            PreparedStatement insertStatement = connection.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO my_table(SOME_DATA) values(?)", RETURN_GENERATED_KEYS)
    ) {
        connection.setAutoCommit(false);
        log.info("Deleting any existing records from staging table...");
        deleteStatement.executeUpdate();

        log.info("Inserting given records in staging table...");
        long start = currentTimeMillis();
        List<String> records = requestData.getData();
        List<List<String>> partitions = partition(records , MAX_ROWS_PER_INSERT);
        int partitionCount = 0;
        for (List<String> recordIds: partitions) {
            log.info("Partition [{}/{}] - Inserting [{}] records in staging table", ++partitionCount, partitions.size(), recordIds.size());
            for (String recordId: recordIds) {
                insertStatement.setString(1, recordId);
                insertStatement.addBatch();
            }
            insertStatement.executeBatch();
        }
        connection.commit();
        log.debug("Total time taken to insert [{}] rows: {}ms", records.size(), (currentTimeMillis() - start));
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        connection.rollback();
        throw new GenericRuntimeException(e);
    }
}
```

Comment: You should be using `connection.setAutoCommit(false)`, depending on whether your RDBMS supports multiple transactions and one of that size. Using the batch statement inside the forEach loop not outside could be very inefficient too.

Comment: It’s technically not inside a loop. A fixed bunch of rows being executed in batch to get the best performance. Also, does setting autocommit to false revert the whole transaction in case something goes wrong?

Comment: My point is that you can create one prepared statement for all `recordIds`, not one per iteration of `recordIds`.

Comment: understood. I've taken inputs from the accepted answer and moved the prepared statement call outside the partitioning loop. Tested few scenarios and it works fine. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [JDBC specification](https://download.oracle.com/otndocs/jcp/jdbc-4_3-mrel3-spec/index.html):

> In the example, auto-commit mode is disabled to prevent the driver from
> committing the transaction when Statement.executeBatch is called. Disabling
> auto-commit allows an application to decide whether or not to commit the
> transaction in the event that an error occurs and some of the commands in a batch
> cannot be processed successfully. For this reason, auto-commit should always be
> turned off when batch updates are done. The commit behavior of executeBatch is
> always implementation-defined when an error occurs and auto-commit is true.

<sub>(section 14.1.1)</sub>

> When auto-commit is disabled, each transaction must be explicitly committed by
> calling the Connection method commit or explicitly rolled back by calling the
> Connection method rollback, respectively.

<sub>(section 10.1.1)</sub>

Although section 14.1.1 specifically is about `Statement`s, it mentions that the same behavior should be assumed for `PreparedStatement`s (which are described in section 14.1.4): If auto-commit is set to true, then `executeBatch` commits the transaction but the error behavior depends on the driver implementation and should not be relied upon. Therefore, the proper way (as suggested by the spec) is to set auto-commit to false.

> I wish to rollback all changes in proper ACID way.

What do you mean by "all"? If you are referring to an individual partition, then you can call `connection.rollback()` within the `catch` block. If you are referring to all partitions then you could set some flag within the catch block (perhaps via some `AtomicBoolean`) and then commit or rollback depending on the value of the flag. In my opinion, in this case it would be better to not use `forEach` but a for-loop and break out early once an error occurs:

```java
connection.setAutoCommit(false);
for (String[] recordIds : partitions) {
    try (PreparedStatement pstmt = ...) {
        for (String recordId : recordIds) {
            pstmt.setString(1, recordId);
            pstmt.addBatch();
        }
        pstmt.executeBatch();
    } catch (SQLException ex) {
        connection.rollback();
        throw new GenericRuntimeException(ex);
    }
}
connection.commit();
```

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanation. I implemented your suggestions along with additional point from @DuncG to move prepared statement call outside the loop.